# Simple receive and return Python server?

Tags: python-3.x, http, server

I need to start up a Python server locally for testing purposes. All it needs to do is reply with the JSON that it received in the request.

I've implemented the required functionality using Node.js. I'd like to rewrite it in Python since it's being used to test a Python service. I haven't been able to find any clear examples of how to do this. From what I can tell it requires knowledge of network programming that I currently don't have (Explanations and/or resources material about what's happening on the network level would be appreciated!)

Node.js code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const http = require("http");

const PORT = process.argv[2]

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let data = "";
    req.on("error", err => {
        throw err;
    });
    req.on("data", chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on("end", () => {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        res.write(data, () => res.end());
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Dummy server listing on port: ${PORT}`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has many framework, an easy one it Flask!

https://medium.com/@aliciagilbert.itsimplified/a-slick-crud-application-built-using-python-with-flask-and-sqlite3-to-teach-simple-mysql-queries-bd75e1109582

[Updated]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    parameter= request.args.get('parameter', default = 1, type = int)
    return "Hello Flask!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Save in app.py and run "python app.py", will listen on port 5000 by default - http://localhost:5000/

Comment: agreed. flask is very simple and lightweight. but I think you can probably write some code to help this gentleman.

Comment: Right, add a snippet!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have said above I'm look for a solution that doesn't require any extra dependencies